# Allah orphans everyone yet he is Rahman Raheem?

Tags: orphans

Allah or God orphans nearly everyone. Losing your parents is one of the most traumatic periods of one's life. Why does a Benevolent merciful make each and every soul suffer this much? Forget the eternal damnation part for now, that most of humans and jinn are going to hell.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as-written, it doesn't seem to be an honest question seeking knowledge about the topic of Islam so much as a rhetorical question attempting to prove a point. We are not a site for argument and debate.

Answer (score 1):

When a person loses his parents, Allah is Ar-Rahman because the person is still breathing Allah's air out of His mercy.

Allah is Ar-Raheem because he is still drinking Allah's water.

As for why people lose their parents, it is because everyone has to go to the Aakhirah eventually. That person will himself die one day as well.